# Values of attributes not shown frontend after import products

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, reindex

How can i solve values of attributes not shown frontend.

my excel format :

[image]

And my back end have all details :

[image]

And my front end look like :

[image]

Comment: When i go to individual product edit page, just click save button without any changes, and clear cache -> and my values of attributes display on front end

Comment: And if you clear the cache without saving?

Comment: sorry, i couldn't get you,

Comment: without saving mean,

Comment: After you import the product data, however you're doing that, are you clearing the caches?

Comment: @Richard : yes but no use,

Comment: @Richard : NOTE :: When i go to individual product edit page, just click save button without any changes, and clear cache -> and my values of attributes display on front end

Comment: which means every time i go to the each and every single product edit page, just click save button, without any changes, right after asking clear cache,  then only values of attributes of values displayed in front end

Comment: any idea about this error >>

Comment: Hi Jeeva, Can you come to chat?

Comment: sure,, i will come to chat

Comment: could you pls join here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42290/jeeva

Comment: @MohitKumarArora : Did you get my chat address